# How to Get the Value of Elements from Console in Javascript

Tags: javascript

First, I am pretty new to Javascript. I am trying to grab the value of an object and I can see all the information I need in the console, I just don't know how to access it. For instance, I'm looking at an HTML Collection, made from a dropdown. It has:

```
>0: option
>2: option
   value: "6"
   text: "apple"
   spellcheck: true
   textContent: "apple"
>3: option
   value: "2"
   text: "test"
   spellcheck: true
   textContent: "test"
>4: option
...
```

Inside each of these are a whole host of parameters and values. My question is, how do I search, select the parameters and use the values, in JavaScript? Keep in mind, the order and number of "option" will change. Value, in this case, is something of - value - It uniquely identifies the text "test" and "apple".

I can list all these out, easily enough, by selecting them and outputting them in the in console...

```
var a = document.getElementById("whatever");
a
```

but how do I access all those sub-properties? Also, I don't know what the proper terminology is for these parameters and values, in order to effectively search Google for an answer, if someone could help me with that, as well.

Comment: In your `getElementById` example, what is `a`? Do you want the property `a.value` directly? Or is there a `<select id="whatever">`?

Comment: All the properties and methods you can access: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: How about `a.value` or `a.text` or `a.textContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access those properties simply with a period, `a.value`.

If you want to loop over a HTML collection, the simplest way is using a for loop:

```js
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var a = options[i];
  
  // Get values
  var value = a.value;
  var text = a.textContent;
  
  if (text == 'Audi') {
    console.log('The value of "Audi" is ' + value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>
```